# jQuery basics - hiding by ID

Tags: jquery

As the title states; I want to hide the `div` when I click it. That isn't happening, what's wrong with my code?

```
<head>
  <script src="js/var_dump.js"></script>
  <script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="kill">Disappear!</div>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#kill").click(function() {
        $("#kill").hide();
      })
    }}
  </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Any error messages in your console?

Comment: You have a syntax error: `}}` in the last line (should be `});`).

Comment: Yup, syntax error: http://jsfiddle.net/uhdpqcxw/1/

Comment: David Thomas, you're right - thank you. However, it still does not work. :(

Comment: @icor103 it actually works. [One more working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0bn06kyj/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bad bracket in last line,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#kill").click(function(){
        $("#kill").hide();
    });
});
 ^^
```

Answer (score 5):

You have a `}` instead of a `)` at the end of your script. Syntax error. :/

Beyond that, you might not be properly referencing your jQuery file, as noted below.

Comment: Good find, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. :(

Comment: @icor103 Are you sure that you're referencing jQuery in the correct location? I might not be being included at all.

Comment: You are right, Sneagan. I added an answer to clarify that - thanks.

Comment: Awesome. I've added that to my answer. Care to accept? ;)

Comment: I was going to, but unfortunately we both missed the semi-colon and panther didn't. ;)

Comment: I gave you a +1, though.

Comment: @icor103 While that semicolon is technically correct, his answer doesn't solve your problem IHMO. Alas, you decide. Thanks for the +1! :D

Answer (score 1):

As other's have noted, the problem was the syntax error. But since you want to hide the same element as the clicked one, there is no need to use a selector again, you can use `this` to refer to the element to which the event handler is bound so

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#kill").click(function() {
    $(this).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="kill">Disappear!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "#kill", function() {
  $("#kill").hide();
});
```

Comment: There is no need in delegated event. Just syntax error in original code.

Comment: If he's using dynamically-added elements, maybe, but otherwise this won't make a difference (though you did tidy up the syntax error, I suppose...)

Comment: fair enough - was only giving an alternative. You guys are right, he has a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

For this, there isn't necessarty to link jQuery, you can use faster and shorter:

```
<div id="kill" onclick="this.style.display = 'none'">Disappear!</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9w49jqx1/

Comment: jQuery's `.hide()` does more than just `display: none;`

Comment: I'm just doing it to learn jQuery (tutorial), but thank you. :)

Comment: Are you really suggesting outdated `onclick=""`?

Comment: @Sneagan: I don't know what icor need exactly. That's alternative.

Comment: @Regent: attr `onlick` isn't outdated, in normal thing and for those basic things asi manipulating with DOM there is no need to use big jQeuery framework. You can use that, if you don't know pure JS, it's your thing. Pure JS isn't outdated, isn't bad, bud you have to be a programmer, not use only Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V from jQuery manual.

Comment: @panther Depends on what you mean by "alternative" ;P

Comment: @Sneagan: many people use `hide()` as `display: none`, `show()` as `display: block`. As I said, we don't know what icor exactly need, so I provide here the simpliest way how to hide (visually) element. The action which many people expect from `hide()`.

Comment: @panther I totally understand, man. However, he's clearly new to this and I wanted to make sure that he understood that these two things are not the same. Misunderstanding the difference between vanilla JS and jQuery methods is a common pitfall. Just trying to help.

Comment: @panther don't be so angry and don't worry about my JS knowledge. Inline JavaScript (same as inline CSS) is discouraged nowadays. There is `element.addEventListener()` (well, and `element.attachEvent()` for old IE), without jQuery. It has several advantages to element's `onclick=""` property.

Answer (score 0):

As many pointed out, I had a syntax error. That was the proper fix for the information I gave - but I'm answering my question because I already told multiple people that it doesn't work.

I forgot to include the subfolder in my script src, oops. It's all good!

Thanks!